# Cauchy's integral formula at the border

Tags: complex-analysis

let $$f : \overline{D(0,R)} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
be continuous on $\overline{D(0,R)}$ and  holomorphic on $D(0,R)$. Show $\forall z \in D(0,R)$
$$I_R := \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D(0,R)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z} d\zeta = f(z)$$

I know for $r \in (|z|, R)$
$$I_r = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D(0,r)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z} d\zeta = f(z)$$

how can do I show $I_r$ converges to $I_R$ as $r \rightarrow R$.

---

Comment: Uniform continuity of $f$ on the closed disk will be helpful.

Comment: write $r=cR, 0<c<1$ so express all integrals on the same space (whether it is the circle of radius $R$ with measure $d\zeta$ or $(0, 2\pi)$ with measure $d\theta$) and use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Comment: is there a method without using this theorem. I haven't learned Lebesgue integrals or seen this theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $r_0$ such that $|z|<r_0<R$, and consider the compact annulus $A=\{\zeta\in\Bbb{C}\,:\, r_0\leq |\zeta|\leq R\}$. Define $F(\zeta)=\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\cdot i\zeta$. Then, continuity of $f$ on the closed unit disk implies that $F$ is continuous on $A$. Since $A$ is compact, $F$ is actually uniformly continuous on $A$.

Now for any $r\in [r_0,R)$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|f(z)-\int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta\right|&=
\left|\int_{|\zeta|=r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta - \int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta\right|\\
&:=
\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{it})}{re^{it}-z}\cdot ire^{it}\,dt-
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(Re^{it})}{Re^{it}-z}\cdot iRe^{it}\,dt\right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^{2\pi}F(re^{it})\,dt-\int_0^{2\pi}F(Re^{it})\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_0^{2\pi}|F(re^{it})-F(Re^{it})|\,dt.
\end{align}
Use uniform continuity to finish off the argument.